# How can I set UIPickerView at other than the default index?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have an integer having value of 5 and I want to start my UIPickerView with this index, now what should I do?
normally UIPickerView is on default 0 index row, but I want it on index which is user defined, as can be 5, 6 or any other digit.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Assuming your picker is referred to in a property "myPicker", then in viewDidLoad, go:

```
[self.myPicker selectRow:rowInt inComponent:componentInt animated:NO]
```

Comment: what are rowInt and componentInt ?

Comment: they're integers saying what row of what component you want to pre-select.

Comment: what do you mean by inComponent?

Comment: A picker can have more than one "wheel". The default date picker is a good example--it has separate spinner sections for date, hour, minute, etc (depending on how you configure it). In Cocoa-Touch-ese, those are "components".

Comment: if I want to select first item from picker-view what should pass in parameter

Answer (score 1):

**Update for Swift 4.2**:

To set the default row in a UIPickerView,

```
  myPicker.selectRow(5, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

where myPicker is the name of the UIPickerView and 5 is the index of the desired row.